# Install Java 5 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, apt-get

I need to install Java 5 in my Ubuntu 12.04. Can't do it by apt-get anymore.

Downloaded the .bin from 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html 
and installed it.

Still, the option for jdk 1.5 doesn't appear after I do: 
sudo update-alternatives --config java

What am I doing wrong? How should I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got it wrong.

For using update-alternatives you have to inform it that you got a new java version:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_40/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_40/bin/javaws" 1
```

And set that version as the default one:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_40/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javac
sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_40/bin/javaws
```

Also, you may want to edit you */etc/profile* to add java to the PATH, although maybe the Oracle installer already did that for you.

Comment: Great.
Please, remember to come back and comment on your results, and accept the answer, of course ;)